# ols_step_all_possible in R not working with variables with numbers

Tags: r, regression, naming

I have a linear regression model that was already done through the "lm" function and I want to perform the "ols_step_all_possible" function on it. Problem is that the dependent variable begins with "2020" (and for descriptive purposes, I don't think it makes sense to remove the number from the variable names). For the lm function I used `` to signify that it's a variable name, but when I perform olsrr on the model I get:

```
Error in str2lang(x) : <text>:1:5: unexpected input
1: 2020_
        ^
```

Does anyone know how to get around this?

Comment: does the column name have a space in it. If so, could you rename to one without spaces?

Comment: I don't follow your argument. Just rename the variable and deal with your "descriptive purposes" in a post-processing step.